# Fullscreen via Javascript on Chrome for Android (tablets)

Tags: android, google-chrome, fullscreen

I would like to have my web app hide the browser tabs and address bar on Chrome on mobile. `document.documentElement.requestFullScreen()` seems to have no effect. `window.scroll(0,1)` doesn't work either on tablets.

If possible, I'd also love a good solution for Chrome and/or Safari on iOS.

Any ideas? I'm on Chrome 29 for Android.

Comment: For a complete solution, check out:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check this sample: [here](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/fullscreen.html)

try to use `webkitRequestFullscreen()`

Also "Lowercased the "S" in `requestFullscreen()` and changed `document.webkitCancelFullScreen()` to `document.webkitExitFullscreen()`. Updated browser compatibility comment." 
via 
[Let-Your-Content-Do-the-Talking-Fullscreen-API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/10/Let-Your-Content-Do-the-Talking-Fullscreen-API)

Comment: It turns out, like many things in browsers, you can only trigger this directly from a touch event handler--no timeouts, no doing it on page load :-(

Comment: the first link is broken.