# How to increase HTML android full screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, android, html, screen, fullscreen

My android device's screen resolution is 1920x1080 px. I wrote the code which requests a full screen on button click:

`document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();`

When site enters to full screen mode the `window` object size is (640, 360). Also same thing with the `screen` object size is not the same as the device's screen resolution. Is it possible to increase the resolution?

P. S. I tested it on Chrome browser.

Comment: Would those topics help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966923/fullscreen-via-javascript-on-chrome-for-android-tablets and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610743/android-browsers-screen-width-screen-height-window-innerwidth-window-inner

Comment: Hi, Am facing same problem. Were you able to find a solution for this? Kindly share with me.

Comment: @Sathish Yeah I found the solution the window size is expressed in logical CSS pixels to convert it to physical pixels just multiply it by window.devicePixelRatio. For example if you want to make canvas object just set canvas scale in CSS to 1.0 / window.devicePixelRatio so you can draw in physical pixels and won't see blurry content.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622663/how-to-increase-html-android-full-screen-resolution